# Map values from external json lookup into array as new key/value pairs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to map new values (from an external json file) into an array (array of arrays or KV pairs, generated from a php file query to mysql) in javascript/jQuery.
The structure of the array is:

```
"results":
[{"gender":"Male","DOB":"1993-09-22","location":"Main","procCode":"43653","preopDx1":"783.3","procedDate":"2008-06-02"},{"gender":"Female","DOB":"2001-11-07","location":"South","procCode":"11403","preopDx1":"216.5","procedDate":"2010-01-01"},...]
```

The json file looks like this:

> [
>       {
>           "CPT": "10021",
>           "RVU": "1.27"
>       },
>       {
>           "CPT": "10022",
>           "RVU": "1.27"
>       }
>   ]

The idea is to

a) Loop thru the myarray values and find each procCode

b) Match this procCode with the identical cpt code in the json file, and

c) Attach each new key/value pair to each 'row' of myarray

```
function addRVU (myarray, myjson){
var newObj = $.map(myarray, function (i,res){
if(myarray[i].procCode == myjson[i].CPT){
    return myarray[i].RVU = myjson[i].RVU;
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what should be the contents of the final array? the first array with only the objects that has a key found in the second array?

Comment: The result should be the entire first array with the addition of the matched k/v pairs - the json file is large, and there will always be a unique value in it that matches the procCode value being looked up.

Comment: By `k/v pairs` you mean `RVU: "1.27"`?

Comment: yes, that was what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

```
// First, convert JSON file into an object keyed off CPT code:
var jsonObj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    jsonObj[json[i].CPT] = json[i];
}

// Now update myarray elements
for (i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
    // $.extend copies properties from 2nd object into 1st object
    $.extend(myarray[i], jsonObj[myarray[i].procCode]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for `if(myarray[i].procCode == myjson[i].CPT)`, you only matched the json and array with same index. loop to match all element in json should fix your problem.

or something like using a hash to map the `RVU`

```
h = {};
$.each(json, function(i, e){
    h[e.CPT] = e.RVU;
});

$.each(ar, function(i, e){
    e.RVU = h[e.procCode];
});
```